# Would a "downcast if block" be a reasonable language feature?

Tags: c#, syntax, language-features, type-casting

Consider the following "if cast":

```
class A     { public void f1() { ... } }
class B : A { public void f2() { ... } }

A a = foo(); // might return A or B

if ( a is B ) {
    //  Inside block, implicitly "redeclare" a as type B
    //  It's B, go for it
    a.f2();
    //  Wouldn't compile.
    a = new A();
}
```

We don't enter the block unless `a` is a `B`, therefore within the block, the compiler treats `a` exactly as if it had been declared as type `B`. You could assign null to it in the block if it's a reference type, but it would be a compile-time error to assign `new A()` to it, for example (thanks @ThomasEding for bringing up that question).

Anything that could break that assumption that `a` is `B`, could just as easily break the following legal C# as well:

```
if ( a is B ) {
    B b = a as B;

    b.f2();
}
```

The former looks to me like syntactic sugar for the latter.

Even if this feature makes sense, I'm sure Anders Hjelberg's lads have more useful features to implement. I'm just wondering if it's a worse idea than I think it is.

**UPDATE** A serious objection would be that the feature as described adds semantics without adding syntax: From one version of the language to the next, the meaning of the above block would change significantly. It would be more tolerable with a new keyword. But then you'd be adding a new keyword.

### Update

A more redable version of this feature was implemented in C#7:

```
object object2 = new List<Test>();

if (object2 is Dictionary<String, int> foo)
{
    Console.WriteLine(foo.Keys);
}
```

Comment: I've seen: `if(auto b = cast(B)a){b.f2();}`

Comment: @ratchetfreak but couldn't this potentially throw a InvalidCastException ?

Comment: not if the cast was designed to be falsy when not valid (C++ dynamic_cast does that)

Comment: Delphi has an 'as', for example `(Sender as TButton)`

Comment: This feature is already implemented in ActionScript . In my perspective though, I think this feature can easily confuse people. There was even a question in stackoverflow "ActionScript: Is there ever a good reason to use 'as' casting?" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/996478/actionscript-is-there-ever-a-good-reason-to-use-as-casting so I guess, I am not the only one that is getting confused :)

Comment: @JohnSkoumbourdis I don't know ActionScript, but from reading the answers there, I get the impression that ActionScript's `as` is very similar to [the existing C# `as` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) -- which I haven't heard of being a source of confusion. But I don't know how the feature would fit in with a dynamic language. That is, assuming ActionScript really still is one, which I'm not sure of :)

Comment: Another language that has a similar feature is FORTRAN: The SELECT TYPE construct (http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS2MB5_14.1.0/com.ibm.xlf141.bg.doc/language_ref/typecon.html) is basically a switch that switches on types, implicitly changing the type of the variable accordingly. Now, it stands to reason what it tells us about a language feature if FORTRAN has it...

Comment: I'd argue that this sort of "language feature" is actually hiding poor design. In the vast majority of cases where this is used, polymorphism should be used instead.

Comment: @Maybe_Factor Virtually any feature can be abused. This should be used only when virtual methods are not an option. There are such cases.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's assume features start with 0 points, rather than with [-100 points](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericgu/minus-100-points) (due to costs associated with implementation, design, etc.).

This feature strikes me as confusing.  I've already declared that a is an A.  If I want to know the compile-time type of a, I only have to look in one place, at the declaration.  While I acknowledge that the implementation is relatively simple (use the code substitution you describe in your question), this also argues in favor of not implementing the feature; it's easy for coders to do it, too.

The truly horrifying thing is that the type of a variable can magically change immediately after a `}`.  C# very deliberately prevents this from happening (see [Simple names are not so simple](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/simple-names-are-not-so-simple)).  So, I absolutely hate any version of this feature that fails to introduce a new variable during the cast.

If you find yourself constantly casting your types so as to access members of derived classes, it makes me suspect you are misusing inheritance.  Personally, usually in code where I'm using such a conditional, I'm going to break out of my function if the cast fails.  So, my code would look more like this:

```
B myB = myA as B;
if (myB == null) return;
```

Which would, under some variant of your proposal, become this:

```
if (!(myA is B)) return;
```

or (introducing a new name)

```
if (!(myA to B myB)) return;
```

or, using [declarative expressions](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Language%20Feature%20Status&referringTitle=Documentation) (this is a variant on [Jimmy Hoffa's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/236335/15162))

```
if (!a.To(out B myB)) return;
```

With the exception of the approach using declarative expressions, all of these features require learning new C# syntax for a feature that is not at all painful to deal with.  The declarative expression approach is nice in that it is the [general case of a specific feature](https://ericlippert.com/2012/07/17/should-c-warn-on-null-dereference/); i.e. allowing coders to make use of an assignment and conditional using a single expression.

The only cost to the declarative expression approach is that it won't work universally; it only works if your special `To` method is implemented and visible in your current scope.  However, that's a price I'm willing to pay to avoid adding yet more syntax to the C# language; I won't bother using such an extension method unless I'm dealing with code which constantly requires it (and probably not even then).

In summary: This feature isn't needed quite often enough to justify adding new syntax to the language.  However, the more general feature, declarative expressions, may be worth the cost (which is why Microsoft is probably going to pay it).  It not only handles this case, but also handles the annoying two-statement `TryParse` case (and, like your proposal, makes for clean scope; the type is only in scope on the inside of the conditional).

**Update: [Declarative Expressions were cancelled](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/568820).**

**Update 2: [C# 7.0 is adding "out variables"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/).** This might be enough for my final example (`if (!a.To(out B myB)) return;`).  [C# 7.0 is also adding "Is-expressions with patterns"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/#user-content-is-expressions-with-patterns), which allows, `if (!(o is int i)) return;`.  This is basically the feature you asked for.

Comment: I'd forgotten about declarative expressions, and that does pretty much split the difference between my suggestion and C# 5.0. And I can feel the objection, of having the type of `a` change at the curly brace. There are probably more confusing features in C#, but even so (or maybe especially *if* so) I'm sympathetic to to an aversion to adding more.

Comment: Is there any way to emulate the conditional-disposal behavior of a C# `for` loop (which disposes the enumerator if it implements `IDisposable`) without boxing?  One could say `var d = enumerator as IDisposable; if (d != null) d.Dispose();`, but that would cause all structure-type enumerators to get boxed.  Is there any boxing-free alternative?

Comment: @supercat: I don't know.  That might make a decent question, though.

Comment: @Brian: Unless there's something new I don't know about, there isn't one.  If that's still true, it would imply that a use-downcast-value-if-possible block would allow the expression of semantics which would otherwise not be possible, and which are sometimes useful (the compiler uses them in its own `foreach` construct).  If features started at zero rather than -100 points, I'd say that would be a basis for including it.

Comment: Even more so (not with the scoping I had in mind, but it's a more powerful feature their way): https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/#user-content-is-expressions-with-patterns

Comment: @EdPlunkett: Yeah, that's basically the feature you asked for.  I edited my answer.

Answer (score 5):

As a data point, the Ceylon language allows<sup>1</sup> you to do this.

In Ceylon, you would write:

```
A a = ...
if (is B a) {
   // refer to 'a' as a 'B'
}
```

or

```
if (is B b = some_expression_returning_A ) {
   // refer to 'b' as a 'B'
}
```

There is also a variation of the `switch` statement that allows you to switch on types, in much the same way.  For example:

```
void switchOnEnumTypes(Foo|Bar|Baz var) {
    switch(var)
    case (is Foo) {
        print("FOO");
    }
    case (is Bar) {
        print("BAR");
    }
    case (is Baz) {
        print("BAZ");
    }
}
```

---

<sup>1 - Actually, it requires this, since Ceylon doesn't have an explicit type-cast.  The goal is to avoid core language constructs that can throw exceptions.  They do something similar to design out NPEs.</sup>

Comment: Thanks Stephen, I'd never heard of Ceylon. Checking it out right now.

Answer (score 4):

It's not that it's a bad idea, it's just that there's no point in elevating this to the point of language feature, not even syntactic sugar, you can very easily implement this yourself in C#:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static void AsIf<T>(this object target, Action<T> todo)
    {
        if (target is T) todo((T)target);
    }
}

a.AsIf(aAsB => {your code});
```

Comment: I've actually written pretty much that exact method, but mine was static rather than an extension, so I didn't have to do a separate check for null.

Comment: ...as for pointlessness, well, sure, all it does is let you clean some visual noise out of the code. I was more interested in potential reasons why it was a *bad* idea, than in insisting that it ought to be added.

Comment: This is sort of in the same category as `ForEach<T>`, in the sense that it is trivially implemented and its sole purpose is to cause side effects.

Comment: You could also write for loops and if statements this way. That doesn't mean you should.

Comment: @immibis: There's also direct support for this feature in the case of `foreach` loops (Eric Lippert discusses in [Why does a foreach loop silently insert an explicit conversion](http://ericlippert.com/2013/07/22/why-does-a-foreach-loop-silently-insert-an-explicit-conversion/).  Of course, this behaves differently (it throws an exception on failure).  However, there's also an extension method, `OfType`, if you prefer to skip non-matching types.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done with the new is-expressions coming in [C# 7](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/)

```
class A     { public void f1() { ... } }
class B : A { public void f2() { ... } }

A a = foo(); // might return A or B

if ( a is B b ) {
    b.f2();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I like the idea. It's also not dangerous if you take into consideration some cases.

Consider

```
if (a is B) {
    a.BMethod(); // OK
    a = new B(); // OK
    a.BMethod(); // OK
    a = null;    // Disallow? (Probably OK)
    a.BMethod(); // Disallow? (Probably OK)
    a = new A(); // Disallow? (Probably bad)
    a.BMethod(); // Disallow?
}
```

It certainly is possible to write your extension to fail to compile in such a case, but one would want clean error messages, need to define more restrictions (such as you could only assign a `B` to `a` inside the if-block), throw a runtime exception, or something else.

Consider multi-threaded code using `a`, and `a` gets reassigned inside the as-if block. This would be very hard to do properly in a direct C# translation (it's possible, but not very nice *). This feature wants to be done at the byte code level, where it is trivial to implement.

(*): You would need to assign to a temporary, then assign to the original `a`, then assign to the `a_as_b` compiler generated variable. Even still, I may be missing some important edge cases.

Comment: Right: For anything inside the block, the compiler would have to treat `a` as being of type `B`, with all that that implies. Therefore, I'd let you assign null to it, but not `a = new A()`.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr:** Concurrency Issues

When you write `A a;` you are effectively making the statement "`a` is a variable that can contain objects representable by the type `A`". By changing the variable's type to something lower in the food chain, you would potentially introduce concurrency issues.

For example

```
namespace AsIf
{
class A { public void FA() {} }
class B : A { public void FB() {} }
class C : A { public void FC() {} }

class Program
{
delegate void ActionOnA(ref A a);
static void AToC(ref A a) { Thread.Sleep(5000); a = new C(); }

void main()
{
A a = new B();

// Wait 5 seconds, change a to new C()
ActionOnA action = AToC;
action.BeginInvoke(ref a, (ar) => { action.EndInvoke(ref a, ar); }, null);

if(a is B)
{
// a is implicitly retyped as B for the rest of this block

// B.FB get called on a (an instance of B)
a.FB();
// Sleep 6 seconds
Thread.Sleep(6000);
// B.FB gets called on a (an instance of C)
a.FB();
// 'Undefined behaviour' most likely causing all kinds of crazy
}
}
}
}
```

This is slightly less likely to happen when you introduce `b`

```
// assume everything else is as before

void main()
{
A a = new B();

// Wait 5 seconds, change a to new C()
ActionOnA action = AToC;
action.BeginInvoke(ref a, (ar) => { action.EndInvoke(ref a, ar); }, null);

if(a is B)
{
// introduce b
B b = (B)a;

// B.FB get called on b (an instance of B)
b.FB();
// Sleep 6 seconds
Thread.Sleep(6000);
// B.FB gets called on b (an instance of B)
b.FB();
// Safe! (for now)
}
}
```

This is because `B` is an entirely different variable being used to hold the same object.
What the concurrent function is actually doing is assigning to the variable a which is not directly affecting the object a was holding. Because b now holds a reference to the object that was in `a`, a can get reassigned and nobody would care.

Of course this is an implementation detail. If the compiler were to secretly create a second variable for the `asif` block rather than just reinterpreting a as being of the type `B`, the result would be effectively the same as my second example. Whether such behaviour is expected, obvious or desired is a different matter entirely.

It's not an impossible feature, it's just one that's more work than it's worth really.

Answer (score 2):

In Swift you write:

```
if let b = a as? B {
    ....
}
```

`a as B` would try to convert `a` to type `B` - which for object types would succeed if a actually belongs to class `B` which would need to be a subclass or superclass of `A` to ever succeed. Of course this would only change the type of the reference, not the type of the object behind it. And it would crash on purpose if the conversion fails.

`a as? B` is similar except it returns an "optional B"; the result is `nil` if the conversion fails.

`if let b = a as? B` evaluates `a as? B`. If the result is `nil` then the if is not executed. If the result is not `nil` then it assigns the reference to a non-optional `b` of type `B` and executes the `if`'s body.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen an `AsIf` extension method implemented as such:

```
private static void AsIf<TBase, TChild>(this TBase source, Action<TChild> action) where TChild : TBase
{
    if ((source is TChild) && (action != null))
    {
        action((TChild)source);
    }
}
```

The generic constraints make sure you're attempting to "as-if" something hierarchically allowable.

Answer (score 1):

This is already a common feature in many programming languages. They are called [sum types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union). Classes are an awkward way to simulate sum types in languages that lack them.

Sum types (also called *variants* and *unions*)  are the dual to product types (commonly called *tuples*).  Just as product types allow you to stick to types together to create a compound type that is composed of type 1 and type 2, sum types allow you to create a compound type that is *either* type 1 *or* type 2.

Here's how it works. Let's say we want to represent internet addresses. There are two ways to address a computer on the internet: using its IP address or its fully-qualified domain name (FQDN). The FQDN is a human-readable string, while the IP address is an integer between 0 and 2^32.

Since we want functions that can operate on either of these schemes, we create a sum type

```
type InternetAddress = IP of int | FQDN of string
```

Note that `InternetAddress` is really just a type alias for `int + string`. The identifiers `IP` and `FQDN` serve as labels (also called *constructors* or *injections*) for each "branch".

To create a value of type `InternetAddress`, we *inject* a value into the sum type

```
val my_address: InternetAddress = FQDN "mydomain.com"
```

To use a value of a sum type, we perform case analysis. The instance type of the value determines which "branch" of the expression we take:

```
case my_address of
     IP ip_address -> *branch 1*
     | FQDN host_name -> *branch 2*
```

In either branch, the underlying value of `my_address` binds to the declared variable. So in branch 1, we can use `ip_address` which has type `int`, and in branch 2 we can use `host_name` which has type `string`.

In my opinion, sum types are an indispensable feature of programming languages, and the fact that they are so scarce in today's mainstream languages has caused considerable confusion and errors over the years.

Comment: What does the "..." represent in `Apple of ... |`?

Comment: The type that the `Apple` tag labels. It can be any type. Here is an example: `type Fruit = Apple of (string * int) | Pear of (real) | Orange of (int -> int)`. Of course this example doesn't make too much sense with fruit, but I'm too lazy to think up a better example, and hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: What language is this, so I can look it up? Does this mean that you've got a variable/whatever named `data`, and if it's a `real`, you execute the code in the `Pear data -> ...` branch?

Comment: Both [OCaml](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/data_types_and_matching.html) and [Haskell](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/school/to-infinity-and-beyond/pick-of-the-week/sum-types) have sum types. My syntax is actually SML though, but that's not a common language. I'll elaborate in my answer as to your question